# FB.getLoginStatus() return "unknown" in Firefox when user is logged

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox

In my site I test if a user is logged on Facebook in order to suggest him/her to like my Facebook site page.

Then, I use the conventional Facebook Js SDK function to understand if the user is logged or not:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        fbuid = response.authResponse.userID;
        status = 'connected';
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        fbuid = null;
        status = 'not_authorized';
    } else { // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        status = 'generic';
        fbuid = 1;
    }

    that.evaluateFbStatus(status, fbuid);
}
```

It works perfectly with every browsers except Firefox.

In Firefox it returns always **unknown** even if the user is logged on Facebook and the status is **not_authorized** or **connected**.

Any help is accepted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FB.getLoginStatus always returns status='unknown'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337619/fb-getloginstatus-always-returns-status-unknown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to third party cookies.

To use Facebook SDK functions in Firefox, is necessary to open setting and able third party cookies *Preferences > Privacy > Accept-third-party cookies*

Have a look on [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325967120821879/) for more details.